# Akka Streams Flow through a cache

Tags: scala, akka

Assume I have a cache:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait Cache[K, V] {
  def put(key: K, value: V): Future[Unit]
  def get(key: K): Future[Option[V]]
  def remove(key: K): Future[Unit]

  def getOrElse(key: K)(ifNotFound: => V): Future[V] = {
    apply(key) {
      Future.successful(ifNotFound)
    }
  }

  def apply(key: K)(ifNotFoundFuture: => Future[V]): Future[V] = {
    get(key).flatMap { found =>
      found.map { x =>
        Future.successful(x)
      } getOrElse {
        ifNotFoundFuture.flatMap { value =>
          put(key, value).map { _ =>
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to wrap an existing Akka Streams Flow from A to B with the cache (retrieving from Cache if it has the value, if not then invoking the flow, storing the value in cache, and returning that value).

I have currently done this, but I'm sure it can be done shorter, better or more idiomatic:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Source}

object CacheFlow {
  def apply[A, B](
    flow: Flow[A, B, NotUsed],
    cache: Cache[A, B]
  ): Flow[A, B, NotUsed] = {
    Flow[A]
      .flatMapConcat { a =>
        Source.fromFuture(cache.get(a))
          .map { x =>
            (a, x)
          }
      }
      .flatMapConcat { case (a, found) =>
        found match {
          case Some(x) => Source.single(x)
          case None    => Source.single(a).via(flow).flatMapConcat { x =>
            Source.fromFuture(cache.put(a, x)).map { _ => x }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Two tests follow. I also tried to write a more complex one going against a "real" in-memory Cache where I'd expect three flow invocations, but this was difficult due to race conditions.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures.whenReady
import cats.syntax.option._
import scala.concurrent.Future

class CacheFlowSpec extends FlatSpec {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val input = List("one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three")

  val alwaysSuccessfulCache = new Cache[Foo, Bar] {
    override def put(key: Foo, value: Bar): Future[Unit] = Future.successful(())
    override def get(key: Foo): Future[Option[Bar]] = Future.successful(Bar(key.value).some)
    override def remove(key: Foo): Future[Unit] = ???
  }

  val alwaysMissingCache = new Cache[Foo, Bar] {
    override def put(key: Foo, value: Bar): Future[Unit] = Future.successful(())
    override def get(key: Foo): Future[Option[Bar]] = Future.successful(None)
    override def remove(key: Foo): Future[Unit] = ???
  }

  private def runTest(cache: Cache[Foo, Bar], expectedFlowInvocations: Int) = {
    var flowInvocations: Int = 0
    val flow = Flow[Foo]
      .map { x =>
        flowInvocations = flowInvocations + 1
        Bar(x.value)
      }

    val cacheFlow = CacheFlow(flow, cache)
    val output = Source(input)
      .map(Foo)
      .via(cacheFlow)
      .map(_.value)
      .runWith(Sink.seq)

    whenReady(output) { x =>
      x.toList shouldEqual input
      flowInvocations shouldEqual expectedFlowInvocations
    }
  }

  "CacheFlow" should "only use cache if it has data" in {
    runTest(alwaysSuccessfulCache, 0)
  }

  it should "always use flow if cache is empty" in {
    runTest(alwaysMissingCache, input.size)
  }
}
```